# Reverse look-up with a map

Tags: c++

What is a good solution when I have a map whose key/value pairs are made up of the following

```
struct Hexagonal_Coordinates { int x, y; };

class Hexagon {
    // stuff
}
```

and I need a reverse look up? That is, determining the coordinates of a `Hexagon` that was previously placed into the map.

I could copy the `Hexagonal_Coordinates` used as key into the respective `Hexagon` object, but that opens up the possibility for mismatches and duplicating data is generally bad.

Comment: why is using the coordinates a problem, are there different objects at the same coordinates

Comment: [Boost.Bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a bi-directional map, seachable by either key or value. If that's the case, the boost library has multi index container, which does just that:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I think your two basic options are sticking a copy/pointer/reference of the coords in `Hexagon`, or keeping a second map which maps `Hexagon` to its coords. Either way, you have some upkeep.

I guess there is another alternative wherein you can do an exhaustive linear search over the key/values in your original map until you find your `Hexagon`, then return its coords. Simpler, but slower.